# How to handle financial transactions across multiple pods of a service deployed on Kubernetes?

Tags: java, concurrency

So, the question I have is how do companies handle transactions from a user with bad connectivity. The scenario in my head is.

A user X (with $150 in their account) is trying to transfer $100 from their account to someone else's account using an app on the phone. But they happen to have not so good internet connection. The user clicks the transfer button after selecting the recipient and the amount of money to transfer. After the user clicks on the transfer button the user loses connectivity, but the request is sent to the server and it starts the transaction, and in few seconds the user regains the connection and ends up in the same page and they happen to click on the transfer button again. As we know once the request is sent irrespective of the user whether they have the app open or not after they click on the transfer button, the request will be processed.

Imagine the app has a microservice architecture deployed on Kubernetes and the service which handles the transfer transactions have multiple pods. The first time the user X clicks the transfer button the request is sent to pod1 and the next time the request is sent to some other pod. How will this be handled. I imagine Reentrant locks would not work in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such problems of distributed systems are well understood and can be worked around. You have identified a number of issues:

- networks are not reliable
- an external change can be accidentally repeated multiple times
- sessions might be routed to different servers
- it is not clear when an action has “happened”

Repeated submission of the same instruction is a common problem, e.g. known as the double POST problem in the web world.

- There are some UX-level techniques to make double submission less likely, e.g. to lock the user interface when a command is sent, wait until there is a response, and then display a confirmation page.
- A more through technique is to give every command/submission/POST a random ID that can be used at most once (a *nonce*). Upon resubmission the nonce would be reused, and the server can throw the duplicates away. This makes it safe to retry a submission until a confirmation is received.
- Another very sensible technique is to check the expected input state. Instead of a command saying “deduct $100”, it would be “given that the account is currently $150, deduct $100”.

The design pattern here is to make commands *achieve a state*, not *change* the state. Such commands are *idempotent*: given some command or function *f* applied to some state *x*, repeated application of the command should produce the same result as a single application: f(x) = f(f(x)). In this scenario, the state you want to achieve isn't a change to the account, but that an order to change the account was received successfully by the backend.

When you have multiple server instances on your backend, a common technique to keep the data consistent was to pin user sessions to a particular instance. This is a pretty bad approach. A much better approach is to ensure that it doesn't matter which instance receives a request, the source of truth is external to the backend. In particular, there will usually be an ACID-compliant database that will either confirm a durable write of some data, or fail. Transactional changes either complete in their entirety or not at all (e.g. failing transactions could be rolled back). To ensure that transactions will fail when they modify some data, it is important that they assert the current state they are operating on. E.g. instead of unconditionally writing a state

```
UPDATE accounts
   SET money = 50
 WHERE id = user1
```

we would have to guard the state like

```
UPDATE accounts
   SET money = 50
 WHERE id = user1
   AND money = 150
```

The database supplies the necessary locks. Whether your service instances are managed by Kubernetes or a bunch of Perl scripts, it doesn't matter.

The actual solution the banking sector seems to do is to avoid distributed systems for crucial processing tasks. Instead, you can route all crucial operations through a mainframe, and keep a second system available for fail-over. While you likely don't have (and don't want!) a mainframe, it is worth considering that tasks that are crucial from a business-perspective aren't necessarily computationally intensive. Using a single service instance can sidestep issues regarding distributed systems, and potentially improve application performance.

Comment: +1 for the observation that, in real banking, they tend to just avoid distributed systems for such crucial tasks.